# Implement local Html in WebView with App Inventor, it doesn't work input

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview, app-inventor

Implement local Html in **WebView with App Inventor**.

[Local HTML in App Inventor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iWEi.png)
[image]

when I try to use "input" for pick a image in cellphone, doesn't react...

```html
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

<input type="file" id="fileElem" multiple accept="image/*" style="display:none" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
<a href="#" id="fileSelect">Pick some files</a> 

<script type="text/javascript">

  window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect"),
    fileElem = document.getElementById("fileElem"),
    fileList = document.getElementById("fileList");

fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  if (fileElem) {
    fileElem.click();
  }
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent navigation to "#"
}, false);
  
</script>
```

I use WebView in app inventor.
The Html is a local file.
**I only can use style sheets and libraries in the same directory as the main html file.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is not possible to use the `webviewer` component to pick files in App Inventor.**

The `webviewer` is no full browser and you can't pick files like this. You will have to use the `activity starter` for that, see for example [How to pick a file from SD card](https://puravidaapps.com/pick.php).

Btw. generally you can use style sheets and libraries together with the `webviewer`...

**If you use html files including js and css files, which use a directory structure,** you have 2 options:

1. upload all files into the assets of your app and modify all paths inside all html, js and css files to use that main directory,
2. or (probably easier) download your project (aia file) onto your computer, make a backup just in case (you know to have backups is always recommended…) open it using 7zip, drag your complete directory structure inside subdirectory assets, save the modified project (aia file) and upload the modified project to App Inventor

Comment: i'm sorry, I didn't give to understand well. I really need to know how solve this with HTML code. I have experience with imagePicker and activity starter.

Comment: Mire tu perfil y sos de Costa Rica. me es mas facil si te respondo en español. Es triste que no funcione, pero bueno quería hacer el intento. Gracias igual!

Comment: Another option is to host your web-page on Github with your Github account as described here; https://pages.github.com and then point the WebViewer component to the URL.You can set a variable in the web-page to pass messages back-and-forth with AppInventor using the `WebViewString` property. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[image]The solution I used consists of

1. Use `Image Picker` to select a local image on Android disk,
2. Upload it to Dropbox using the API end-point for [upload](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload),
3. Create a [shareable link](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-create_shared_link) to the file on Dropbox using the API, then
4. Modify this link to just the hosted image on Dropbox, and finally
5. Pass the URL as `WebViewString` to display with image tag in HTML with the `WebViewer` component.

This requires a Dropbox account and API key. I can't say whether it is worth all this effort in your specific use-case, it worked in mine. I worked off [this](https://puravidaapps.com/dropbox.php) example from @Taifun to upload the image and added modifications of my own to get shareable link and render in WebViewer.

I am assuming you are familiar with APIs and how to use them. I recommend testing the end-points in Postman or Insomnia first if you decide to go this route. Once you get correct responses (status 200), follow the example to implement the API calls in AppInventor with the `Web` component's POST file method.

Hope this helps. If something is not clear, let me know and I will add more notes.